# Cannot Deserialize Recursively a Class Hierarchy Using JSON.NET

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
class Rule { }
class Condition { List<Rule> Rules { get; set; } }
```

Forget about the remaining properties. I need to deserialize from a JSON string, using a custom JsonConverter. The problem is, I have code for each specific case, but I cannot have it ran recursively, for taking care of the Rules property, each of its elements can be a Condition too.
My code looks like this (ReadJson method):

```
var jo = JObject.Load(reader);
Rule rule = null;

if (jo["condition"] == null)
{
    rule = new Rule();
    //fill the properties for rule
}
else
{
    rule = new Condition();
    //I now want the converter to go through all the values in jo["rules"] and turn them into Rules or Conditions
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? I tried to get the JSON for the remaining part, if the object is found to be a Condition:

```
var json = jo.GetValue("rule").ToString();
```

But I cannot deserialize it like this, it throws an exception:

```
var rules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rule[]>(json, this);
```

The exception is: JsonReaderException : Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Like an array of Rules or possibly Conditions, of course. Something like [ { ... }, { "condition": true, ... } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far from having it working.  After you instantiate correct type of object based on the presence or absence of the `condition` property in the JSON, you can populate the instance using the `serializer.Populate` method.  This should take care of the recursion automatically.  You do need to pass a new `JsonReader` instance to `Populate`, which you can create using `jo.CreateReader()`.

Here is what the converter should look like:

```
public class RuleConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Rule).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        Rule rule = null;

        if (jo["condition"] == null)
        {
            rule = new Rule();
        }
        else
        {
            rule = new Condition();
        }

        serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), rule);
        return rule;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SHctMo

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting this exception when I call serializer.Populate: JsonReaderException : Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path 'rules', line 1, position 31.
My code is the same as the one you have.

Comment: Does your JSON have the same structure as the one in the example I posted, or is it different somehow?  It's hard to diagnose what the issue is without being able to see what I'm working with.  Can you create a [mcve] which shows the problem?  (Easiest way to do that is to fork my example fiddle and change the JSON)

Comment: It is working now, thanks a lot! My mistake, as it usually is! :-)